# How to link progress bar with request send to remote service through gSOAP?

Tags: cocoa, progress-bar, progress, objective-c++, gsoap

I have a Java web service and I am calling it from my Objective-C++ Cocoa application. I generated stubs using gSOAP. My question is how to link progress bar with request send to remote service through gSOAP proxy class?

Comment: Well, what's your specific progress metric?

Comment: Metric is size of transferred data. Request may be "big".

Comment: So you might just need e.g. 5 requests to transfer the data, i.e. just 5 opportunities to update the progress bar with real progress information? Depending on how long the whole process actually takes it sounds like you'd want to implement some kind of guessing/predictive scheme to update the progress bar between these points. Kind of like MS installers are giving you some kind of progress that's usually never even close to the eventual time it takes albeit constantly updating.. ;-)